# Append and Overwrite in Amazon Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

As Redshift is based on PostgreSQL, does it have an option to overwrite or append data in table while copying from S3 to redshift?

Only thing I got is use of triggers but they don't accept any argument.

All I need to write a script which takes an argument as yes/no (or similar) if the data is already in the table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When loading data from Amazon S3 into Amazon Redshift using the `COPY` command, data is **appended** to the target table.

Redshift **does not have an "overwrite" option**. If you wish to replace existing data with the data being loaded, you could:

- Load the data into a temporary table
- Delete rows in the main table that match the incoming data, eg:

  DELETE FROM main-table WHERE id IN (SELECT id from temp-table)
- Copy the rows from the temporary table to the main table, eg:

  SELECT * FROM temp-table INTO main-table

See: [Updating and Inserting New Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html)

Answer (score 1):

Redshift doesn't allow you to create triggers or events like other sql databases, the solution I found is to run update (sql query)though you can use also Python or other language and schedule the Rscript with crontab task.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2019, Redshift supports stored procedures so you can package up a set of queries/statements like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.copy_and_cleanse_data(overwrite bool)
AS $$
BEGIN
    if overwrite IS TRUE THEN DELETE FROM myredshifttable;
    copy myredshifttable
        from 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/category_pipe.txt'
        iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>'
        region 'us-west-2';
    UPDATE myredshifttable SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield, 'foo', 'bar');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Then use or schedule the following query:

```
CALL public.copy_and_cleanse_data()
```